# Reading multiple parquet files using hive table

Tags: hive, schema, parquet

Hi I have 2 parquet files with different no of columns 
1)  name,class,marks
2) name,class,marks,grades

How do I read all the data from both files using a table in hive. Say the table is defined with 4 columns name,class marks,grads?
How do we set parquet.mergeSchema properties in hive?

Comment: have you at least tried to create an external hive table pointing to the location of the files?

Comment: Yes it's done... But the table does not show files from both files. The table displays only 3 columns data name, class,marks and grade is coming as null despite one parquet file in the tbl location is having values for grade

Comment: you should post your CREATE statement. In any case you can try setting parquet.column.index.access=false before executing the CREATE statement.

Answer (score 0):

Parquet supports schema evolution. If you are using Spark SQL reading this files you have to set spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema to true (it is turned off since Spark 1.5.1 as schema merging is an expensive operation). See also [Spark SQL Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html), section Schema Merging.